# ffmpeg, C++ - get fps in program

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have a video which has 23.98 fps, this can be seen from Quicktime and ffmpeg in the command line. OpenCV, wrongly, thinks it has 23 fps. I am interested in finding a programmatic way to find out a video fps' from ffmpeg.

Comment: the commandline version for the ffmpeg fps I use is `ffmpeg -i yourfilenamehere.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'frame=' | cut -f 2 -d ' '` in linux or `ffmpeg -i yourfilenamehere.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | findstr 'frame='` in windows (xp upwards)

Answer (score 13):

To get video Frames per Second (fps) value using FFMPEG-C++

```
/* find first stream */
for(int i=0; i<pAVFormatContext->nb_streams ;i++ )
{
if( pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO ) 
/* if video stream found then get the index */
{
  VideoStreamIndx = i;
  break;
}
}


 /* if video stream not availabe */
 if((VideoStreamIndx) == -1)
 {
   std::cout<<"video streams not found"<<std::endl;
   return -1;
 }
 /* get video fps */
 double videoFPS = av_q2d(ptrAVFormatContext->streams[VideoStreamIndx]->r_frame_rate);
 std::cout<<"fps :"<<videoFPS<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Starting ffmpeg version 3.4 the AVCodecContext has depreciated codec parameter. This `pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO` now will need to change to                                                    `pAVFormatContext->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO`

Comment: In the FFmpeg's avformat.h file near the r_frame_rate there is a comment that says "Note, this value is just a guess!"

Comment: https://abdullahfarwees.blogspot.com/2023/01/how-to-get-frames-per-second-value-from.html old blog but might be useful for some folks !.

Answer (score 3):

A quick look into the OpenCV sources show the following:

```
double CvCapture_FFMPEG::get_fps()
{
    double fps = r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->r_frame_rate);

#if LIBAVFORMAT_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(52, 111, 0)
    if (fps < eps_zero)
    {
        fps = r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->avg_frame_rate);
    }
#endif

    if (fps < eps_zero)
    {
        fps = 1.0 / r2d(ic->streams[video_stream]->codec->time_base);
    }

    return fps;
}
```

so looks quite right. Maybe run a debug session through this part to verify the values at this point? The `avg_frame_rate` of [AVStream](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVStream.html) is an `AVRational` so it should be able to hold the precise value. Maybe if your code uses the second if block due to an older ffmpeg version the `time_base` is not set right?

**EDIT**

If you debug take a look if the `r_frame_rate` and `avg_frame_rate` differ, since at least according to [this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2013-May/004715.html) they tend to differ based on the codec used. Since you have not mentioned the video format it's hard to guess, but seems that at least for H264 you should use `avg_ frame_rate` straightforward and a value obtained from `r_frame_rate` could mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

From `libavformat` version `55.1.100` released in 2013-03-29, `av_guess_frame_rate()` is added.

```
/**
 * Guess the frame rate, based on both the container and codec information.
 *
 * @param ctx the format context which the stream is part of
 * @param stream the stream which the frame is part of
 * @param frame the frame for which the frame rate should be determined, may be NULL
 * @return the guessed (valid) frame rate, 0/1 if no idea
 */
AVRational av_guess_frame_rate(AVFormatContext *ctx, AVStream *stream, AVFrame *frame);
```